# Infinite scrolling issue

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, browserify

I found [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/) of infinite scrolling and tried to perform it the same, but after fixing all mistakes I've found it still doesn't work.

Here's the directive:

```
module.exports = /*@ngInject*/
function scrollDirective($rootScope) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
            var raw = elm[0];

            elm.bind('expressly', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.scrollDirective); 
            }
        });
        }
    };
};
```

Then how it goes on in controller (I have JSON-data in promise)

```
module.exports = /*@ngInject*/
function cardController($scope, dataFactory) {
  var promise = dataFactory.get();
  promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.items = [];
    //$scope.items.push($scope.data[0]);
    var counter = 0;

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
      for (var i = counter; i < counter+9; i++) {
          $scope.items.push($scope.data[i]);
      }
      counter += 9;
    };

    $scope.loadMore();
    }, function(reason) {
      console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
    });
};
```

And finally html:

```
<div class="mdl-grid" scroll-directive="loadMore()"> 
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <md-card>
      <img ng-src="{{ item.url }}" class="md-card-image">
      <md-card-content>
        <md-icon ><i class="material-icons md-36 md-album">photo_album</i></md-icon>
        <h3 class="md-title">{{ item.title }}</h3>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turned up pretty simple. In directive instead of elm I used `$document` and pass parameter `i` to the function. After exploring the guts of `i`, I found all parameters I needed through `i.target.activeElement`. Here is the solution:

```
function scrollDirective($rootScope,$document) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
            var raw = elm[0];

            $document.bind('scroll', function (i) {
                if (i.target.activeElement.scrollTop+i.target.activeElement.offsetHeight +5>= i.target.activeElement.scrollHeight){
                    scope.$apply(attr.scrollDirective); 
                }
            });
        }
    };
};
```